# Calling JAX-RS Web Service from JSF managed bean

Tags: web-services, jsf, rest, jax-rs, managed-bean

I currently develop a Web application that can be accessed over HTTP by an Android application or a Web browser. Both user agents basically provide the same functionalities. The Android app calls RESTful Web Services built with JAX-RS/Jersey, while Web pages are Facelets backed by JSF managed beans.  I thus consider that there are two types of possible entry points to the Web app. The Web services do all the necessary work (accessing the resources, performing the database operations within DAOs, etc.) and most importantly, they must act on their own. Therefore, they constitute an independent layer.

**In order to reuse the code, is it a good practice to call a Web service from a managed bean? Are their life cycle compatible?**

The idea is to inject the Resource object into the managed bean (with CDI, but not necessarily) and to call its methods **programmatically**. The Web service would act as a business delegate (?) to the underlying services.

I widely googled the question but I didn't get a clear answer. I saw some pieces of code where the managed bean invokes a Web service with its URL, but since all my components are located in a single server app, I don't see what prevents me from linking them *directly*.

Subsidiary question on error handling: I am also annoyed with the idea of catching WebApplicationExceptions from the Web service into my managed bean for returning error messages back to the view (with FacesMessage). My father always told me that I should never catch runtime exceptions...So, is there a good way to handle them correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you would be better off having the business logic out from the Web Service into "some central shared code".  Then, then web services and the managed beans would call into the shared code.

I've put the term "some central shared code" in quotes, as what you use depends on your runtime environment.  If you're using a JavaEE container like Glassfish or JBoss, this sounds like a perfect use of EJB and stateless session beans (which are designed to ensure the resources are managed well).  You could also use Spring Beans as the shared code and centralize the logic that way.

It all depends on what you find more comfortable from a development and production sense.  But both support injection, so both the Web Service and JSF Managed Beans could have the services injected as any other resource.

Comment: I agree with @EdH answer. In addition, for error handling, if you separate your business logic into an EJB you can manage errors there and log then into a file, or whatever, and then throw only one single **UnexpectedException** that will be transformed inside your JSF always to the same **FacesMessage** with a friendly text (you can do that even with a filter for simplification).

Comment: Actually, my Web app is deployed in a Tomcat servlet container and I don't (want to) have all the full JEE stack, including CDI.

Comment: Your answer is obviously correct and I validate it, but I felt it was introducing a new _heavy_ layer, and the Web service layer would have done the job perfectly if there was not this problem of error handling. So, thank you, I'm going to introduce the "shared code" you mentioned...

Comment: If you don't want the whole JavaEE layer (although, the Web Profile for JavaEE isn't that heavy), you could introduce just enough Spring to do what you want.  Spring's good that way, where you can bring in only what you want.